# Play Framework 2.5.12 - set multiple filter in application.conf

Tags: filter, playframework-2.5

I'm using Play Framework 2.5.12 (Java version).
When I declare a filter (Filters1) and set below config in application.conf:

```
 play.http.filters = my.filter.path.Filters1
```

It works fine.

But I have two filters:

1. Filters1 extends DefaultHttpFilters class
2. Filters2 extends Filter class

In Play Framework 2.6 , solution is:

```
play.http.filters += my.filter.path.Filters1
play.http.filters += my.filter.path.Filters2
```

I have tried that, but it didn't work in Play Framework 2.5.
What is your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I couldn't handle this problem in application.conf.

Solution :

You have to pass your filter as a parameter in constructor of Filters1 and set it as EssentialFilters.

This is my Filters1 class :

```
import com.rh.ot.web.core.filters.CustomFilter;
import play.Environment;
import play.filters.gzip.GzipFilter;
import play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter;
import play.http.DefaultHttpFilters;
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class Filters1 extends DefaultHttpFilters {

    private final Environment env;
    private EssentialFilter[] filters;

    @Inject
    public Filters(Environment env, GzipFilter gzipFilter, SecurityHeadersFilter securityHeadersFilter, Filters2 filters2) {
        super(securityHeadersFilter);
        this.env = env;
        filters = new EssentialFilter[]{gzipFilter.asJava(), filters2.asJava()};
    }

    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        return filters;
    }
}
```

and Filters2 class :

```
import akka.util.ByteString;
import play.libs.streams.Accumulator;
import play.mvc.EssentialAction;
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.mvc.Result;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

public class Filters2 extends EssentialFilter {

    private final Executor executor;

    @Inject
    public Filters2(Executor executor) {
        super();
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public EssentialAction apply(EssentialAction next) {
        return EssentialAction.of(request -> {
            request.headers().put("Strict-Transport-Security", new String[]{"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"});
            Accumulator<ByteString, Result> accumulator = next.apply(request);
            return accumulator.map(result -> result, executor);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was migrating a Play 2.4 project where the logging filter was hooked up in the Global to Play 2.5 (and of course onto 2.7 at least), and there seemed to have been no way of injecting even a logging filter. Your method worked immediately by adding the logging filter.